# HTML select multiple: show all elements

Tags: html, listbox

How can I make the list box be tall enough to fit all options (desirably hiding the scroll bar)?

It's like setting size equals length, but what's a simple way to do it if the length is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

So you aren't able to hide the scroll bar with just the select tags. You need to add a div to cover it

html:

```
<div class="opt">
  <select multiple='multiple'size=11>
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

css:

```
.opt { 
  display:inline-block; 
  vertical-align:top; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  border:solid grey 1px;
}
.opt select { 
  padding:10px; 
  margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/KingPyrox/eoLdr4pc/

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/victorbasso/v1jdtxoL/1/.
This is the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/victorbasso/v1jdtxoL/2/ (hopefully without scrollbars too).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javaScript.

First, you need to know the height of the option in the select

```
function getOptionHeight(selectId, optionIndex) {
  // Get reference to the select element
  var select = document.getElementById(selectId);
  
  // Get reference to the option element
  var option = select.options[optionIndex];
  
  // Clone the option element
  var clone = option.cloneNode(true);
  
  // Create a temporary container
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  container.style.height = '0px';
  
  // Append the clone to the container
  container.appendChild(clone);
  
  // Append the container to the document body
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  
  // Get the height of the clone
  var height = clone.offsetHeight;
  
  // Remove the container from the document body
  document.body.removeChild(container);
  
  return height;
}
```

Then you need to know how many options there are

```
function countOptions(selectId) {
  // Get reference to the select element
  var select = document.getElementById(selectId);

  // Return the total number of options
  return select.options.length;
}
```

Then, simply multiply the 2 and set the height of your select

```
function setSelectHeight(selectId, height) {
  // Get reference to the select element
  var select = document.getElementById(selectId);
  
  // Set the height of the select element
  select.style.height = height;
}
```

so your code usage would look like:

```
var oh=( getOptionHeight("mySelect",1) );
var ol=( countOptions("mySelect") )-1;
setSelectHeight("mySelect", (oh*ol)+"px" );
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lf1mhw9/)